# How to add single quote at beginning and end of array variable in php using notepad++

Tags: php, notepad++, notepad

I have delared variables like this. I have created more than 100 variables in every page.

```
<?php echo $rsedit[customer_name];  ?>
<?php echo $rsedit[address];  ?>
<?php echo $rsedit[city]; ?>
<?php echo $rsedit[pincode]; ?>
<?php echo $rsedit[contact_no]; ?>
<?php echo $rsedit[email_id]; ?>
```

I  am searching and replacing in notepad++. But it takes long time.

I want following output:

```
<?php echo $rsedit['customer_name'];  ?>
<?php echo $rsedit['address'];  ?>
<?php echo $rsedit['city']; ?>
<?php echo $rsedit['pincode']; ?>
<?php echo $rsedit['contact_no']; ?>
<?php echo $rsedit['email_id']; ?>
```

Tell me the best solution for this to replace together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```regex
Find:    <\?php echo \$(.*?)\[(.*?)\];\s*\?>
Replace: <?php echo \$$1['$2']; ?>
```

### Demo

Comment: Can you tell me how to replace in notepad

Comment: You have tagged with Notepad++ and you can't do this in regular Notepad.  However, you can certainly open the demo link I included above, paste in your code, and then copy out the replacements.

Answer (score 0):

```
Provided all those 100 lines always begins with "echo $rsedit"

in regular notepad you could just CTRL+H(windows) or edit > replace
Then add "rsedit[" on find what
Then add "rsedit['" on replace with //notice the single quote after rsedit[
then tap replace all

to add single quote at the end again CTRL+H(windows)
Then add "];" on find what
Then add "'];" on replace with //notice the position of the single quote
then tap replace all
```

If the variables are different say

```
<?php echo $rsedit1[customer_name];  ?>
<?php echo $somethingelse[address];  ?>
<?php echo $rsedit3[city]; ?>
<?php echo $rsedi6[pincode]; ?>
<?php echo $ftedit[contact_no]; ?>
<?php echo $rsedit[email_id]; ?>
```

Just look for something that is common and use it as a replacement point.For the above code you could replace `"[" with "['"` notice the single quote

then replace `] with ']`

Comment: Thanks  I already did this. But every lines are not same.

Comment: Look for patterns...something that is always there <?php echo $rsedit[customer_name];  ?>
<?php echo $rsedit1[address];  ?>
<?php echo $rsedit2[city]; ?>
<?php echo $someother2[pincode]; ?> .....   The one thing that remains the same after variables is [ so replace [ with ['